Swagger-ui: difference between Intellij and chrome
I have a strange behavior with swagger. The preview of swagger ui in intelij is different from what I had in chrome. I didn't undersrtand the cause, even the number of apis is different. I tried to clean the cache and restart but It didn't work. Please, find attached the two interfaces.
Intellij-swagger-ui:

Chrome-swagger-ui:

